# How do I uninstall Adobe Air?

Tags: macos, adobe-air

I stumbled upon Adobe Air in the Utilities folder of my Mac. I don't use Flash, and I am not aware of having installed any other programs which need Adobe Air.
There were two files - An installer and uninstaller.
Clicking on the uninstaller simply launched a window saying that Adobe Air is already installed on my system! It didn't give me any option to remove it. So I deleted both the files.

A few minutes later, a window opened on its own, asking me if I wanted to update Adobe Air now, or later!

How do I make sure this cheeky application has been removed completely?

Answer (score 15):

This worked fine for me:

- Download the Air Application from http://get.adobe.com/air/ (Note the
  locations you saved it)
- Mount (Open) the DMG
- From Terminal:
  `sudo "/Volumes/Adobe AIR/Adobe AIR Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe AIR Installer" -uninstall`

From [here](http://techbookshelf.com/2010/03/02/how-to-uninstall-adobe-air/).

Comment: In my machine I had to run this command against this path instead _/Applications/Utilities/Adobe AIR Uninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe AIR Installer" -uninstall_

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /Applications/Utilities/Adobe\ AIR\ Uninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe\ AIR\ Installer -uninstall
Password:*****
Uninstalling Adobe AIR (all versions)
done
```

Comment: You should just have edited n13's post instead of posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try installing Adobe AIR again and then running the uninstaller again in the hope that it would work correctly the second time.  For me though, running the uninstaller removed these files and directories:

```
/Applications/Adobe/Flash Player/AddIns/airappinstaller/airappinstaller
/Applications/Utilities/Adobe AIR Uninstaller.app
/Applications/Utilities/Adobe AIR Application Installer.app
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/airappinstaller.rsrc
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/airappinstaller
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Adobe AIR.vch
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Adobe AIR Updater.app
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Adobe AIR Application Installer.app
/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Adobe AIR/
```

But it didn't remove these files and directories:

```
/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AIR/
$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/AIR/
$HOME/Library/Caches/com.adobe.air.Installer
$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.air.els.<some-hash>.dat.plist
$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.air.els.<some-hash>.dat.plist.lockfile
```

They all look safe to remove - certainly nothing that wouldn't be replaced by reinstalling AIR.  I haven't looked exhaustively, but I'm struggling to find anything else with AIR's fingerprints on it.